# How to protect applications ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, source-code-protection

My boss have given me assignment to find how a web based application developed in .NET can be protected. As per agreement products developed in our company are an asset of the company and even non-developers can access the code. But my boss still he wants to know how he can protect products in case a developer steals the code and tries to launch it from his home ?

Please guide how this can be controlled.

Comment: So, just to clarify: is your boss concerned about the developers (you guys) stealing the source code and releasing the product? Or is he concerned about customers being able to reverse-engineer the product? It sounds like the first one, but you might want to double-check with him.

Comment: Are you here for the few extra points you get for an accepted answer or for the discussion? It doesn't make sense for him to accept answers unless they are actually satisfactory.

Comment: Tell your boss that you have over 9,000 firewalls to protect it.  Seriously though, there is absolutely nothing you can do and your boss is asking something impossible because he doesn't understand technology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the developer has:

1. the source
2. the knowledge of how the the technical aspects of the system hang together
3. the knowledge of what the customers really want, beyond simple technical facilities

there isnt much you can do - things like Obfuscation and even Code Protection only kick in after a compiler has seen the code. Assuming you're going to allow the developers to compile the full end-to-end code on their machine, it's not hard to disable anything that one could ordinarily put in place to guard against customers stealing code.

Having said that, in the case of a web based application, you won't be using something like Obfuscation as a first-line of defense mechanism - only as a (tinfoil-hatted) defence in depth mitigation against the threat of decompilation *after* someone has compromised your site and got themselves a copy of your assemblies.

Ultimately this is why protection around stuff like this is written in legalese, not a computer language.

(BTW this is a [duplicate of this question which has some great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232228/protection-of-code-from-its-own-developers) - which I unfortunately only discovered after retagging this)

Comment: +1 You are totally correct this is a legal question,  not a computer science question.  Its 100% impossible to protect your code like this.

Answer (score 5):

What if a developer memorizes the code part by part and retypes it at home day after day. Ask your boss, what would he do about that? Reset the developer's memory like in 'Men in Black'? LOL. Shrinks do have a medical term for your boss' attitude.

My advice is this: tell the boss to let it go or hire other developers that he can trust.

Comment: +1 good way of putting it. You could technically achieve a (pretty moot) prevention of this by silo the developers and only giving them access to the source of their corner. But obviously this sort of mentality is not going to lead to a successful team, system or company...

Answer (score 4):

Just off the top of my head... rip out all their USB ports, CD rom drives, and disable their internet.

Answer (score 3):

You can't protect the source code.

Any developer worth his salt knows exactly how to reproduce whatever he wrote. He is the one who made it, so he can do it again.

The only thing you can do is legally protect your products with patents and copyrights.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your Boss to believe on his/her developers. And tell him/her to give Good salary to Developers. Code is written by developer, so any how they can rewrite their own code.

Answer (score 1):

[Legalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement_of_software), and thats all that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is not a technical problem. You control developer code theft by hiring a lawyer.

It is difficult enough "protecting" redistributable .NET code, but I would think it is (nearly) impossible to protect the code against your own developers.

**Update:**
Here's also a constructive suggestion, for the sake of the challenge. Organize developers like a spy network -- have them work on individual modules based on agreed-upon specifications in separate geographical locations, with you acting as an information hub. Integrate the modules yourself or with the help of one trusted person. In this way, none of the developers have all the pieces to make the application work "at home".

Comment: But what about the person acting as a hub?

Comment: Once the project finishes, he or she would have to be shot.

Comment: As I mentioned in one of the other comments, the overheads of codifying your mistrust of your developers in this manner are very unlikely to outweigh the costs. And all they have to do is go on SO or twitter and they'll suss out who's working on their team by finding people who are asking questions about how to get work done in a team of non-trusted developers. Hang on - how was the OP trusted to be on SO :P

Answer (score 0):

Use source control software correctly (Visual Studio Team System has this built in). You should then know who has the code.

This won't stop anybody running the code and distributing it but would make the person who last checked it out somewhat accountable for its whereabouts.

Comment: (Not the -1er) Can you explain how this is going to prevent someone from running the code or provide anythig useful to anyone?

Comment: (-1er) Using a SCM is a great tip, but it won't help with code theft -- by definition, developers will need to get the source code and build the project locally (in a common scenario).

Comment: Agreed - somebody who has access will always be able to take it away (code is just text after all). Source control would prevent non-developers getting any access to the code and, as I said, create an audit trail of developer access.

Comment: 0: This is relatively obvious. Do you feel that such an audit trail (of what, SCM GETs? - they arent normally logged) would actually form a useful part of a legal attack or defence? Doesnt really make sense. Ultimately this doesnt answer the question unless you can explain it better to me.

Comment: I wasn't aware that GETs wouldn't be auditing - if so then I agree SCM would give little benefit in this situation. If not then although it wouldn't form the backbone of any legal evidence it could help the actual investigation and lead to admissable evidence.